# Why is my website not updating text color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have recently started managing my own VPS with Webmin. I uploaded my website files to the server and everything was fine. I've been updating the website on my local PC with WAMP and when I got to a point that I wanted to upload the files to my server, I did so and all content works fine except the 'color' property of certain text.

When I browse my website through WAMP at localhost, the font color is fine. But when I upload the exact files to my server, the font color is wrong. I've tried 3 browsers, and cleared the cache multiple times but the text will not change colors and I cannot figure out what is causing it. I've tried seeing what was causing the font color with firebug, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

My website is luckylinks.net and one of the pages where the problems occurs is http://luckylinks.net/terms.html. All of the text on that page is supposed to be white, but it is black. Any ideas?

Comment: It's colored white when I viewed it.

Comment: I'm showing white text in both my FF and Chrome... double check the caching issue.  I also don't see anything in the CSS that it would be inheriting black text color from.

Comment: Are you sure you cleared your cache? Try pressing Control-F5 to reload your page. The color CSS declaration is at style.css:204 and it always applies, I think. So I do not think you should change the page.

Comment: Another confirmation: it's white (in Firefox). Try http://browsershots.org/ to snapshot your page to make a comparison. Hope it helps.

Comment: Very odd. I'm seeing black text in Chrome, FF, and IE9. @JanusTroelsen, when I inspect style.css in Chrome Dev Tools, it only goes up to line 192. The only `color` rule I can find in any of the stylesheets is on line 138, for `.ui-accordion-header a`, set to `#222;`.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmations guys. I've tried everything everyone said and it still shows as black text on my screen. Thanks for the browsershots.org link, I will be saving that. It shows the text as white. I've never had any problems like this. Is it possible it has something to do with server configuration? I'm fairly new to managing my own server.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with your server, this is a client-side problem. Are you sure you didn't disable custom style sheets or forced the text colour in all your browsers?

Comment: @Vektor: You should try completely replacing the document and seeing if your browser would catch that. If you still see the page, you know something is cached somewhere.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen Thanks for your help. No, I have not disabled custom style sheets in any browser or force the text color. So far I've tried on IE, FF, Chrome(on 2 separate computers), and Safari from 2 separate iPhones. The only thing in common with all of these devices is the router/internet connection we share.

Comment: You can inspect the code in Chrome to see if it is how you expect it to be. If your browser settings are normal, I am sure the browser is using an old version of your page. Using [Chrome Development Tools and its Elements pane](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements) it is quite easy to see which CSS statements are overridden. If the newest code is loaded in the browser, but the color definition at style.css:204 is overridden, you will see it with a strike-though. If there is a css "color" statement further up that is not strike-though, that is the culprit.

Comment: I've checked the server, and I'm positive that files that no longer exist on the server are being loaded somehow. But I also don't think its any of my browsers, as I've tried 3 browsers, each on 2 separate computers, as well as 2 browsers on mobile devices. I'm stumped.

Comment: I looked at your page with FireBug and cannot find any mention of "color" in you stylesheets anywhere.  Fix your stylesheets.

Comment: @JimGarrison That's the problem, I'm looking at the exact files on the server and they show numerous 'color' defintions, all changing the content color to white. The files just aren't being served for some reason.

Comment: Install Firebug on Firefox (or use Chrome developer tools) to see what is actually being served.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jim. But I think I've established that old/incorrect files are being served, but I can't figure out why. The files being served are no longer on the server at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I simply needed to Purge the cache on CloudFlare. Also, to do any updates, you should enter development mode on CloudFlare before applying the updates.

Answer (score 0):

I see white. I noticed your styles use the color name "white"- maybe try changing to the hex value just for fun? But it looks like you've got multiple confirmed people viewing white so it's probably a caching issue.
Try clearing your cache, restarting your browsers, and doing a shift+refresh as well.

```
color:#FFFFFF
```

would be white.

Comment: I've tried clearing the cache on IE, FF, and Chrome, as well as restarted them all and even rebooted my machine. It still shows black text. Thanks for your help though, I know this is a VERY strange problem.

Comment: @Vektor And you dont have some sort of a debugger or browser override forcing your text to be white? I inspected it with firebug and it showed correctly there, too. Hmmmm... very strange. Please let me know once you figure out what's up!!

Comment: I'll be sure to let you know. I've checked the server, and I'm positive that files that no longer exist on the server are being loaded somehow. But I also don't think its any of my browsers, as I've tried 3 browsers, each on 2 separate computers, as well as 2 browsers on mobile devices. I'm stumped.